# Error trying to insert textbox contents into my database C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, textbox

I am trying to put the contents of the text box into my table called [Questions Space] but the QuestionText":",connect); is underlined with errors saying

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

and

> Invalid expression term ',' and ')'

I can't seem to find anywhere to solve this problem I'm sure the solution isn't that difficult but I'm a newbie.

```
string QuestionText = QuestionBox.Text;

SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Space]) VALUES ({0})"QuestionText,connect);
```

I've tried this as well but it doesn't work either:

```
 SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Space]) VALUES ({0})"QuestionText,connect);
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Here's my full code for the button if anyone would like to see that:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();

        int checkedradiobutton = 0;


        if(radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            checkedradiobutton = 1;

        }
        else if(radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            checkedradiobutton = 2;
        }
        else if(radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            checkedradiobutton = 3;
        }



        switch (checkedradiobutton)
        {
            case 0: MessageBox.Show("Please select a question type");
                break;
            case 1: 
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Type]) VALUES (1)",connect);
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                break;


            case 2:

                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Type]) VALUES (2)",connect);
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                break;
            case 3: 

                SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Type]) VALUES (3)",connect);
                command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                break;

        }




        string QuestionText = QuestionBox.Text;

        SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Space]) VALUES ("QuestionText")",connect);

        command5.ExecuteNonQuery();




    }
```

Comment: Sorry the title was wrong, I corrected it

Comment: Updated the answer to solve your problem with single quote near old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the below,

```
SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Space]) VALUES ('" + QuestionText + "')",connect);
```

Having said that, you should not use this mechanism of creating your command text. You should use command parameters to mitigate the risk of SQL Injection

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This will also take care of single quotes in your values.

An example below:

```
SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Space]) VALUES (@QuestionText)",connect);

command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionText", QuestionText);
command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much for the extra help as well! Works like a treat!

Answer (score 2):

It should be this: `String.Format("INSERT INTO Questions ([Question Space]) VALUES ('{0}')",QuestionText)`

You are missing the single quotes around the insert statement for text, and your sql was coming out as something like

```
INSERT INTO Questions([Question Space]) VALUES (This is the question text)
```

Comment: any idea why the code stops at command5.ExecuteNonQuery(); and says     An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'old'. ?

Comment: The 'old' is the second word of the string in the text box

Comment: @mot375 As mentioned if you use command parameters you will not face this error. It is most probably because you have a single quote near old.